# Event-handling 101 - How can I capture an event from outer <div> in embedded <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hoping there is a way to do this, with one event-handler. Allow me to explain:

Considering this simple html snippet that replicates without cruft the idea of what I am dealing with:

```
<div class="navRow">
     <!-- 5 child divs in here -->
    <div id="box-bambin" class="yellow-box navbox">
    Content 1
    </div>

    <div id="box-mamiepom" class="green-box navbox">
    Content 2
    </div>

    <div id="box-amusailes" class="orange-box navbox">
    Content 3
    </div>

    <div id="box-fracomousse" class="red-box navbox">
    Content 4
    </div>

    <div id="box-pommeEnchantee" class="blue-box navbox">
        Content 5
    </div>

</div>
```

I had assigned event handler to all inner divs, but I am pretty sure one can just set one event handler on the outer div and capture the events on inner divs. When I set the event handler on outer div .navRow, my mouse captures the outer div event.

```
  $('.navRow', context).mouseover(function (event, domEle) {      

     var targetBox =  $(event); 

     console.log("captured event target = " + event.currentTarget);

        $('.navRow').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') == $(event.target).attr('id')){
               // Found match do nothing.
              console.log("matched = " + $(this).attr('id'));
            } else{
              console.log("this = " + $(this).attr('class'));
              //* change for image.
            }
        });

  });
```

At this point I am simply trying to get the inner div that was moused-over. Please, I am very much in need of any critique / hints on bad usage I am doing. Nothing I have tried gives me inner elements #id that was moused-over.

I tried .target and currentTarget properties but they don't give proper inner div object id.

Is there a way around this, or would all inner objects need to be binded to event handlers?

- I had a similar piece of code  working proper with inner event handlers, just wanted to replicate code behavior, with one single event-handler if possible.

I was thinking this is how bigger applications would work, I mean not having all these event handlers would simplify things somewhat, it seems?

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) on the parent for that "single hander", and [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get the others that are not the target.

```
//"attach to .navRow an onmouseover for .navbox"
$('.navRow').on('mouseover','.navbox',function () {      

     //the target. "this" is the DOM element .navbox
     //to use jQuery on it, we wrap it in $();
     var target = $(this);

     //the siblings that are not the targets
     //since "target" is already a jQuery object
     //we can use siblings() on it to get its siblings
     var nonTargets = target.siblings(); 

});
```

Comment: Ah. Dude. siblings() is kind of the icing on the cake too. Those eventhandling functions, is it wrong my arguments? On some objects values are returned undefined but sometimes it returned the event and dom element.

Comment: @stefgosselin i'm not sure i understand you but, handlers provide arguments. I just omitted them since the target of the handler is the `this` in the function. For more details on the event (like key pressed, etc.), you should add the first argument. Also, the details of the event depends on the event as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's new [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to accomplish this with one event binding to the parent like this

```
$('.navRow').on('mouseover','.navbox',function(){
   // now source object is this
   $source = $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the which .navbox was clicked then you should have

```
$('.navbox').each(function(){
```

Comment: Ok, but what would capture the events? Is there not anything else needed?

Comment: @stefgosselin I was just pointing out that you should have .navbox in the .each() and not .navRow because .navbox is the class of the inner divs in which you wanted to find out which was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/) could be:

```
$('.navRow').mouseover(function (evt, domEle) {      
     evt = evt || event;
     var targetBox =  $(evt.target || evt.srcElement); 
     console.log("You hovered #" + targetBox.attr('id'));
});
```

This way you can still retrieve the event initiating element (`div.navrow`).

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/aDaRj/) showing both this method and the `.on` method for delegation